# IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed PYTHON, SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite, integrity, notnull

Im trying to store my json file to the popNames DB but this error pops up.
My Json file is a dictionary with the country being the key and the person names as key_value. In my DB I want to put the country as the first element as a primary and the names in the subsequent column in the db table

Could anyone help me with this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hn3U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Every `INSERT` call creates a new row in the `PopNamesDB` table. Your code creates many such rows: the first row has a `country` but NULL for all the other columns. The next N rows each have a null `country`, a value for `colName`, and NULL for all the other columns.

An easy way to fix your code is to change your followup `INSERT` calls (on line 109) to change the row you created earlier, instead of creating new rows.  The query will look something like

```
cur.execute(''' UPDATE PopNamesDB SET ''' + colName + ''' = ? WHERE country = ?''', (y, c))
```